# inserting code snippet into table

Tags: pdftex

In my current latex report, I have to insert code snippets into Latex table. I have tried with `listing` but, **listing  is not working**. I have written following latex code  using **verbatim**. But, I want some professional look. Could you suggest me -- **how could I insert code snippet in latex table ?**

```
begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
    \small
    \centering
   \begin{tabular}{ | >{\raggedright}p{4cm} | >{\raggedright}p{4cm}| >{\raggedright}p{7cm} | >{\raggedright}p{9cm} |}   \hline
    \textbf{Domain/Application} & \textbf{Vocabulary} & \textbf{Network} & \textbf{Architecture/Computational Logic} \cr \hline 
        \emph{Building-Automation Domain} \vspace{0.1in} \\ Regulating Temperature \\ \vspace{0.5in} Detecting Fire & \begin{verbatim}
    regions:
        Building : integer;
        Floor: integer;
        Room : integer;
    abilities:
        sensors:
            TemperatureSensor
            SmokeDetector
            BadgeReader
        actuators:
            Heater
            Alarm
    \end{verbatim} 

    & \begin{verbatim}
    Device 1:
      Ability: TemperatureSensor
      Location: Building 1, Floor 2, Room 2
    Device 2:
      Ability: SmokeDetector, TemperatureSensor
  Location: Building 1, Floor 2, Room 2
    \end{verbatim} &  \begin{verbatim}
    AverageTemperature:
      generate AverageTemperature : TempStruct ;
      consume AvgTempMeasurement from hops: 0  : Room;
      in - region : Building | Floor | Room ;   

    FireAlarmComputation
      generate FireAlarmState : FireAlarmStruct ;
      consume AverageTemperature from hops : 0 : Room ;
      consume SmokeDetector from hops : 0 : Room ;
  in - region : Room ;
    \end{verbatim}  
    \cr \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \label{vsdfasdfasfada} 
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listings` is working.

Add to your preambule:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Listings style
\newcommand\mystyle{\lstset{
language=R,                     % Specify your language here
basicstyle=\ttfamily,           % Specify basic style
otherkeywords={Device,Abilty},  % Keywords
keywordstyle=\color{red}        % Add other options
}}

% Custom environment for your listings
\lstnewenvironment{mylist}[1][]
{
\mystyle
\lstset{#1}
}
{}
```

In the table's cell:

```
% Previous cell here
&
    {\begin{mylist}
    Device 1:
      Ability: TemperatureSensor
      Location: Building 1, Floor 2, Room 2
    Device 2:
      Ability: SmokeDetector, TemperatureSensor
      Location: Building 1, Floor 2, Room 2
    \end{mylist}}
&
% Next cell here
```

Note opening and closing curve brackets before and after `mylist` environment.